# How to loop through a function for each item in list?

Tags: python

i need to find the price of something from a function that has been imported.

so, lets say that a function from an imported file called stock.py is:

```
def stock_price(item):
""" Returns the current price of an item """
return _ALL_PRICES[item]
```

_ALL_PRICES[item] is a list full of name and prices

here is a example :

'Rice'             : 14.55,

'coke'             : 1.55,

the item function is,

```
 item = stock.stock_list(location_name)
 """eg; bread, rice, coke"""
 for x in sorted(item):
    print (x)
```

**and i need to make a function that will give me the price of all the things in the list.**

but doing this doesn't work.

```
price = stock.stock_price(item)
for x in price:
    print (x)
```

i was told that, stock_price() expects a single item, such as 'coke'. You will need to loop through each of the items in the stock.stock_list(), and for each one of those items, call stock_price().

can you please help with this :(.

Comment: `for x in sorted(item): print(stock.stock_price(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this

```
item = stock.stock_list(location_name)
 """eg; bread, rice, coke"""
for x in sorted(item):
    print stock.stock_price(x)
```

OR

```
item = stock.stock_list(location_name)
complete_list = [stock.stock_price(x) for x in sorted(item)]
```